# Exposed filter with "inverted" checkbox: Checked = view all, Unchecked = filtered

Tags: views

I have a view that shows commerce products, with an exposed filter to show only items with stock >= 0. So, if the checkbox is checked, it will hide out-of-stock items.

I would like to reverse this so that if the checkbox is checked, all items are shown, and if it is not checked, only the filtered items (stock >= 0) are shown.

The label could then be changed to "Reveal items that are currently not available".

Any idea how to do this?
I could probably do this with some hook_form_alter() and stuff, but I am more interested in something to configure with the Views UI.

(Not that I shy away from custom modules in general, but I like to avoid stuff that is hardcoded to one specific view name and display id and field name..)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but you might be able to do it by using 2 filters. Add a non exposed filter that filters by stock > 0. Make sure it is below your current filter. Views filters in order from top to bottom. So if the page loads and that check mark is un-checked you will only see products with a stock greater than 0. If they then check the box it will re-load and filter by your stock >= 0. That might work. As I said I have not tested this.